# Issue with send via JB

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

I have installed the connector with salesforce and when I try to send an email using a salesforce data event via journey builder I get the following error message: The email specified for the job has not been approved for sending to the selected audience (s). EmailID: ..... Reason: Audience is not appropriate for this email.

I tried to test the synchronization of salesforce objects and there is no problem on the connector side.

Do you have any idea what it might be?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with connector or Journey Builder - seems that you have `Approvals` enabled in Content Builder and are unable to send unapproved emails:

> Approvals is a process for reviewing and approving various objects in
> the Marketing Cloud. This process allows you to submit an email into a
> process which requires an approver to approve it before it can be sent
> to an audience.

You have two choices here:

- select a different email, which has already been approved
- or request approval for the existing email, once it's approved, you will be able to send it

Source:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_approvals.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks for your help!